# Bootstrap button input group wont display correctly with <form> tags

Tags: php, css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I'm working on a social networking Facebook type proof of concept project for college and I'm trying to get a Bootstrap, multi-button input group to display properly for a comment box.

I would like to have the text area, with a Comment and Like button on the right hand side, with the whole input group filling the width of the panel as seen below.

[Trying to achieve this!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUWTR.png)

The problem is when I add in my `<form>` tags, the formatting of the entire group within `<div class="row">` goes crazy and forms a little box on the left hand side (screenshot below).
If I take out the `<form>` tags formats properly, but I'm just not sure how to manage the `<form>` tags/where to put them to achieve this multi-button group.

[How it displays currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9w1L.png)

The code below is a few undos later to when the forms weren't broken, just so you know this isn't how I originally went about achieving it, but what i've succumbed to for now.

If anyone knows how to achieve this I'd be so grateful!

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        //Get relative timestamp for current post
        $timestamp = strtotime($row['StatusTimestamp']);
        $stampRelative = CheckTimestamp($timestamp);

        echo '<div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">'.$row['UserName'].'<small class="postTimestamp"> '.$stampRelative.'</small></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    '.$row['StatusContent'].'
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer clearfix">';
        echo '      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-11">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <form action="'.CommentOnStatus($row['StatusID']).'" method="post">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="comment" placeholder="Post a comment...">
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Comment</button>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="statusId" value="'.$row['StatusID'].'">
                                    </span>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-1">
                            <form action="'.LikeStatus($row['StatusID']).'" method="post">
                                <button type="submit" id="like" name="'.$row['StatusID'].'" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Like</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your code. This should work fine. Let me know if this does not work. THere are minor problems of placing the elements. Please Use this in your row :

```
  <div class="col-lg-11">
       <form  method="post">
           <div class="input-group">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="comment" placeholder="Post a comment...">
                 <span class="input-group-btn">
                      <button class="btn btn-default" style="border-width: 1px 0 1px 0;border-radius: 0;" type="submit">Comment</button>
                      <button type="submit" id="like" name="'" class="btn btn-primary" style="border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;">Like</button>
                  </span>
                  <input type="hidden" name="statusId" value="">
            </div>
        </form>
   </div>
```

This is my output

[image]

Comment: let me know if this is not what you want

Comment: That seems to have fixed it! Yeah exactly what I was looking for. I need to reflow in my dynamic form actions and ID's tomorrow when I have more time and I'll mark this as answered if it works. Thanks so much!

Comment: I m just glab i could help. Let me know if it still does not work. :D :D

Comment: It worked! I created a new function in the form action attribute to handle the multiple submit buttons and everything works smoothly now. Thanks again for the help! [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/P8JhLPP.png?1)

Answer (score 0):

Use the class`navbar-form` in your form. It should work fine now.
So form will look like `<form action="'.CommentOnStatus($row['StatusID']).'" method="post" class="navbar-form">`

Comment: This did change the look slightly but only reflowed the position of the button and added some padding. I presume I have to redo the whole row div with the proper multi-button input group formatting? [Attached image](http://i.imgur.com/iJ7mtJi.jpg)